# GDAL merge; Why add 0.1?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-merge

In the implementation of gdal_merge:

https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_merge.py

a value of 0.1 is added to the conversion from geo-referenced coordinates to pixel indexes:

```
tw_xoff = int((tgw_ulx - t_geotransform[0]) / t_geotransform[1] + 0.1)
tw_yoff = int((tgw_uly - t_geotransform[3]) / t_geotransform[5] + 0.1)
```

What is the reason for adding 0.1?

Comment: I believe this is done to avoid issues resulting from numerical inaccuracies: the `int` operator converts a floating point number to an integer by rounding down, so you might end up with a value for the offset that's off by one.

For instance, the expression `int(1.0 / 100000001 * 100000001)` evaluates to `0`, not to `1` like the algebraic solution. By adding a small value you push the result of the division over the edge of the next integer value if you're already close to it. Another approach to avoid this problem is to use `int(round( ... ))`.